# XNA Model rendering: texture is there, but messed up

Tags: model, 3d, xna, textures, blender

I just found out how to export a 3D textured model from blender and successfully imported it into my xna program, but it seems to be sampling the texture wrong. At first I thought that my custom HLSL effect file was messing up, but when I used the BasicEffect to render it, the exact same thing happened. Here is an image of the texture file:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-q4D37og8BMUk41R2pxVFR2Tm8/edit?usp=sharing

and this is how my program is rendering the cube:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-q4D37og8BMUk1sWEJSMUY4ZVk/edit?usp=sharing

Please note that I'm not talking about the interpolation of the texture, My custom HLSL file renders textures with point clamp, this is using basic effect. Also, If you are wondering, I have no lighting effects on it yet, for some reason, the texture sampler darkened the red pixels on the face. The face should have the same red color as the sides.
Here's my model loading method:

```
private Model LoadModel(string assetName, out Texture2D[] textures) {
        Model newModel = Content.Load<Model>(assetName);
        textures = new Texture2D[newModel.Meshes.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in newModel.Meshes)
            foreach (BasicEffect currentEffect in mesh.Effects)
                textures[i++] = currentEffect.Texture;

        return newModel;
    }
```

and here is my draw model method:

```
private void DrawModel(Model model, Texture2D[] textures, Matrix wMatrix, string technique) {
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        float aspectRatio = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.View = Player.Camera.ViewMatrix;
                effect.Projection = Player.Camera.ProjectionMatrix;
                effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

I have absolutely no idea what could cause this. Let me know if I should post more code, also if the links don't work. Any help at all is appreciated

Comment: The texture is very small and being stretched over a large screen space, have you tried using a higher resolution texture?

Comment: That worked :O. Thanks man. Any idea why that happens with small textures? I didn't think the resolution would matter that much with sampling

Comment: There are three methods of texture sampling, point, linear and mipmap. Point is the fastest and lowest quality method. But which ever method you use, it's going to struggle when you ask it show the texture at many times its original size.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping, I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now.